# Opencv Vec3b vs uchar different output

Tags: opencv

I am trying to get pixel value before doing some calculation. When i run the below code at loc (10,10)i get the below answers. I am not sure why the color value is different than others. When do the same for loc (0,0) i get same answers for all. Image is black and white with 3 channels. Or is it that for 3 channels i should always use Vec3b?

```
char imageName[] = "0001.png";
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(imageName);

cout << "Image rows is: " << img.rows << " cols is : " << img.cols << endl;
cout << "Image channels " << img.channels() << endl;
cout << "Image depth " << img.depth() << endl; //CV_8U == 0 

cout << (int)img.at<uchar>(10, 10) << endl;
cout << (int)img.ptr(10)[10] << endl;
Scalar intensity = img.at<uchar>(10, 10);
cout << intensity << endl;

Vec3b color = img.at<Vec3b>(10, 10);
cout << color << endl;
```

output:

Image rows is: 96 cols is : 72

Image channels 3

Image depth 0

103

103

[103, 0, 0, 0]

[164, 164, 164]

Comment: since you read in a 3channel image: `cv::imread(imageName)` - the uchar access is actually illegal. (you'll find out, if you run a proper debug build, it will throw an exception there)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, then i should use the Vec3b then. i dont have the pdb files for opencv libs probably that is why i didnt get any error. :)